# Must declare the scalar variable, Why when its a Param?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This gives me an error on `@ID` and `@Name` saying `Must declare the scalar variable`, but i don't understand why if it is a param.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ins_eProductFull]
    @Name nvarchar(400)
    ,@ID int

    AS
  BEGIN

    DECLARE @ID2 int

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Table (Name) VALUES (@Name)

    SET @ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    EXEC dbo.StoredProc1 
      @ID = @ID, 
      @Name = @Name, 
      @ID2 = @ID2

  END
  GO
```

Comment: Is the error coming from `Ins_eProductFull` or from `StoredProc1`???

Comment: I think executing the SP with the param/var is causing it

Comment: It won't let me save the `Ins_eProductFull` sp because its throwing these errors.

Comment: it was the StoredProc1 causing the issue.. i can never figure out these line numbers errors. Thanks for your effort... Now i guess i'll just wait for my -1 vote from Aaron then we can call this post finished.. hehe. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you post the code for StoredProc1 (the parameter types should be enough)?

Comment: Ha ha, very funny. Why do you seem to think you know who down-votes your questions? I'm not the only one on StackOverflow with the ability to click the down arrow.

Comment: hehe, i'm just kidding with you Aaron. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only problem I see on your code is the first comma that should not be there. Other than that everything works fine

EDIT:

to whoever downvoted it, see for yourself:

```
create table Table1(Name varchar(50))

Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Ins_eProductFull]
@Name nvarchar(400),
@ID int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID2 int

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Table1 (Name) VALUES (@Name)

    SET @ID2 = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    EXEC dbo.StoredProc1 
      @ID = @ID, 
      @Name = @Name, 
      @ID2 = @ID2

END
GO

CREATE  procedure dbo.StoredProc1 
@ID int,
@Name varchar(50),
@ID2 int
as 
begin
    select @ID,@Name,@id2
end


exec [Ins_eProductFull] 'a',1
```

result:

```
1   a   NULL
```

and the NULL is because there is no identity on my test table

Comment: What comma that shouldn't be there?

Comment: I think I saw a comma before the @Name parameter. My typo probably

Comment: I removed it.. it was the StoredProc1 causing the issue.. i can never figure out these line numbers errors.  Thanks for your effort.

Comment: np, would you please remove the downvote if you were the one who did it? thanks